# Generating n samples using a vector

Tags: r

How can i generate 1000 samples with size 8 from a vector containing 20 elements in R. How can i make a single sample a thousand?
**please help**

Comment: Welcome to CV. Note that this questions to this site are presumed to be agnostic wrt specific software. So, no one is obliged to provide R code in their response.

Comment: NOTE that DJohnson's answer is actually inaccurate for Cross Validated if the post had an R tag on it.

Comment: You can simply do `sample(x, 8e3, replace = TRUE)` and then just convert to a `matrix` or `split` to vectors

Answer (score 2):

If X is the vector containing your 20 elements, the you can use:

sample(X, 8, replace = TRUE, prob = NULL)

Loop this statement 1000 times as below:

```
Results <- matrix(, nrow = 1000, ncol = 8)
X=1:20
for (i in 1:1000){
  Results[i, ]<-sample(X,8,replace=TRUE,prob=NULL)
}
```

Each row in the matrix called Sample should now represent each of your 1000 samples.

Comment: For loop in R? My eyes are bleeding :)

Comment: it is a very well constructed for-loop, though (in R-terms). preallocated matrix, etc. very readable, too.

Comment: @hrbrmstr I see absolutely no reason for a `for` loop here. How is this different from just `matrix(sample(X, 8e3, replace = TRUE), ncol = 1e3)`?

Comment: i'm just saying that it's not a bad for loop construct (not commenting on question answer efficacy)

Comment: He's just not satisfied with my answer :)

Comment: David I really like your proposition.

Answer (score 0):

I think using `*apply` family is better than using a `for` loop as `R` is vectorized.

Below is a code that even work on multicore

```
X=1:20    
# on linux

library(parallel)
library(magrittr)
mclapply(rep(list(X), 1000), sample, 8, replace = TRUE, prob = NULL) %>%
    simplify2array
# on windows
    cl <- makeCluster(detectCores()) # type = "MPI" / type = "PSOCK"
parLapply(cl, rep(list(X), 1000), sample, 8, replace = TRUE, prob = NULL) %>%
   simplify2array
stopCluster(cl)
```

Comment: `apply` is no more vectorized than a `for` loop. It has been discussed too many times already.

Comment: you sure the overhead of parallel ops is warranted for such a small task?

Comment: There is 'n sample' in the question title. So maybe if n is great :)